# C++ Free memory

Tags: c++, free

I would like to ask how to properly free memory in my program.
(free(): double free detected in tcache 2
timeout: the monitored command dumped core)

In the adVersion method, I create a linked list with the current instance values. In the variable m_History I have a reference to the following element. In the method, I add the current contents of the instance to the end of this linked list.

In the copy constructor, I copy everything and the linked list belonging to the given instances.

I enclose important parts of the program and in the link the whole program https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3xzaa3mfh

//EDIT: I little change the adVersion method, please can you check if it is OK?

```
    class CFile
    {
            uint8_t *m_Data;
            uint32_t m_Len;
            uint32_t m_Position;
            uint32_t m_Capacity;
    
            size_t m_LenHistory;
            CFile *m_History;
    
    };
    
    CFile::CFile(void)
    :m_Data(nullptr), m_Len(0), m_Position(0), m_Capacity(0),m_LenHistory(0), m_History(nullptr)
    {
    }
    
    CFile::~CFile (void)
    {
        delete[] m_Data;
    
        //Delete linked list
        while (m_History)
        {
            CFile* old = m_History;
            delete[] old->m_Data;
            m_History = m_History->m_History;
            delete old;
        }
        m_History = nullptr;
    }
    
    CFile* copyLinkedList(CFile *list)
    {
        if(list == nullptr) return nullptr;
    
        CFile* result = new CFile;
        result->m_Capacity = list->m_Capacity;
        result->m_Len = list->m_Len;
        result->m_Position = list->m_Position;
        result->m_LenHistory = list->m_LenHistory;
        result->m_Data = new uint8_t[list->m_Capacity];
        memcpy(result->m_Data, list->m_Data, result->m_Len);
        result->m_History = copyLinkedList(list->m_History);
        
        return result;
    }
    
    // Copy construkctor
    CFile::CFile(const CFile &src)
    : m_Data(new uint8_t[src.m_Capacity]),
      m_Len(src.m_Len),
      m_Position(src.m_Position),
      m_Capacity(src.m_Capacity),
      m_LenHistory(src.m_LenHistory)
    {
        memcpy(m_Data, src.m_Data, m_Len);
        m_History = copyLinkedList(src.m_History);
    }
    
    void CFile::copyWithoudLinkedList( CFile &src )
    {
        m_Capacity = src.m_Capacity;
        m_Len = src.m_Len;
        m_LenHistory = src.m_LenHistory;
        m_Position = src.m_Position;
        m_Data = new uint8_t[src.m_Capacity];
    
        memcpy(m_Data, src.m_Data, m_Len);
    }
    
    void CFile::addVersion  ( void )
{
    CFile *tmp = m_History;
    CFile *prev;

    if(!tmp)
    {
        tmp = new CFile();
        tmp->copyWithoudLinkedList(*this);
        this->m_History = tmp;
        this->m_History->m_History = nullptr;
        m_LenHistory++;
    }
    else
    {
        while(tmp)
        {
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->m_History;
        }
        
        tmp = new CFile();
        tmp->copyWithoudLinkedList(*this);
        prev->m_History = tmp;
        prev->m_History->m_History = nullptr;
        m_LenHistory++;
   }
}
```

Comment: `delete old` calls the destructor of `old` and hence everything is freed again. You can replace the `while` block with `if (m_History) delete m_History;` Then `m_History` will take care of its subnodes. Note however that when your list is very long there is a danger of stackoverflow. In that case you can write another method `clear` to clear nodes then let destructor call `clear`.

Comment: Minimal example code would better illustrate the issue. The non-pointer members of `CFile` are likely unrelated to a memory management problem. So at most, the class should be `class CFile {
    uint8_t *m_Data;
    CFile *m_History;
};`. At most. This brings up an important piece of information -- can you reproduce the error if you reduce the class to `class CFile {
    CFile *m_History;
};`? If you cannot, that should be mentioned in the question. If you can, then do so! The simpler the example, the easier it is for people to answer, and for others to learn from your experience.

Comment: @WhatsUp And that will release the m_Data of the given items in the linked list?

Comment: Yes, they are deleted in the first line `delete[] m_Data;`

Comment: {Tongue-in-cheek} Probably the best way to avoid the memory problems would be to use a `<vector>` instead of a C array for the data and a `<forward_list>` instead of manual list handling for the nodes...

Comment: @WhatsUp The placeholder hint for entering comments is *"Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."*

Comment: @JaMiT Sorry for that. Each subforum of StackExchange has a different culture, and I haven't been active on StackOverflow for many years ...

Comment: @DevSolar why tongue in cheek, they are perfectly good suggestions and sometimes OPs dont know about them (hard to believe ,I know ,but STL is a mystery to many c++ newcomers))

Comment: @pm100: I guess I have heard "doing this for learning purposes" or "our instructor doesn't want us to use the library" so often that I can no longer believe this being an actual option for an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The best way to avoid problems with your manual memory handling is not having any. Large parts of the C++ standard library are there so that you don't have to bother with implementing standard data structures.

First off, instead of using `uint8_t *m_Data;` (which requires allocating and freeing memory) use [`std::vector< uint8_t >`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which does it for you.

Second, turn `class CFile` from doing two things -- holding data, and implementing a list -- into doing just one, holding data.

```
#include <vector>

struct CFile
{
    std::vector< uint8_t > m_Data;
    // ...
};
```

Third, get a linked list of `CFile` instances via the standard container [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list):

```
#include <forward_list>

std::forward_list< CFile > cfile_list;
CFile cfile { { 0x23, 0x42, 0xff } };
cfile_list.push_front( cfile );
```

Since you now don't have to assign memory manually at any place, you also don't have to release it manually either.

Answer (score 2):

While I totally agree with the other people that you shouldn't be managing memory yourself, unless you are developing a new data structure not available in the standard library, I also like people who want to "do it themselves" to learn and make mistakes.

So, since I'm on vacation, I took the chance to redo it my way (not with much attention, so don't trust this too much).

The basic idea is to separate the content of file from the manager of the versioning system. I've tried to avoid changing names and algorithms from yours too much, but the lists stuff was really too strange and filled of potentially uninitialized variables.

I didn't add anything related to move constructors, but they are definitely important if you plan to manage memory yourself. Take a look at the copy-and-swap idiom.

See if this fits your needs:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// using namespace std; // Not a good idea

class CFile {
    struct CFileContents {
        uint8_t *m_Data = nullptr;
        uint32_t m_Len = 0;
        uint32_t m_Capacity = 0;
        uint32_t m_Position = 0;
    
        CFileContents() {}
        CFileContents(const CFileContents& other) :
            m_Data(new uint8_t[other.m_Capacity]),
            m_Len(other.m_Len),
            m_Capacity(other.m_Capacity),
            m_Position(other.m_Position)
        {
            std::copy(other.m_Data, other.m_Data + other.m_Len, m_Data);
        }
        CFileContents& operator=(const CFileContents& rhs) {
            if (m_Capacity < rhs.m_Capacity) {
                delete[] m_Data;
                m_Capacity = rhs.m_Capacity;
                m_Data = new uint8_t[m_Capacity];
            }
            m_Len = rhs.m_Len;
            std::copy(rhs.m_Data, rhs.m_Data + rhs.m_Len, m_Data);
            m_Position = rhs.m_Position;
            return *this;
        }
        ~CFileContents() {
            delete[] m_Data;
        }

        const uint8_t* data() const { return m_Data; }
        uint32_t length() const { return m_Len; }
        uint32_t pos() const { return m_Position; }

        void truncate(void) {
            m_Len = m_Position;
        }

        uint32_t write(const uint8_t *src, uint32_t bytes) {
            if (m_Position + bytes > m_Capacity)
            {
                while (m_Position + bytes > m_Capacity)
                    m_Capacity += m_Capacity / 2 + 10;

                uint8_t *tmp = new uint8_t[m_Capacity];
                std::copy(m_Data, m_Data + m_Len, tmp);
                delete[] m_Data;
                m_Data = tmp;
            }
            std::copy(src, src + bytes, m_Data + m_Position);

            if (m_Position + bytes > m_Len)
                m_Len = m_Position + bytes;

            m_Position += bytes;
            return bytes;
        }

        uint32_t read(uint8_t* dst, uint32_t bytes)
        {
            if (m_Position + bytes > m_Len) {
                bytes = m_Len - m_Position;
            }
            std::copy(m_Data + m_Position, m_Data + m_Position + bytes, dst);
            m_Position += bytes;
            return bytes;
        }

        bool seek(uint32_t offset) {
            if (offset <= m_Len) {
                m_Position = offset;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    struct CNode {
        CFileContents data;
        CNode* next = nullptr;

        CNode() {}
        CNode(const CNode& other) = delete;
        CNode& operator=(const CNode& rhs) = delete;
        ~CNode() {
            delete next;
        }
    };

    uint32_t m_LenHistory;
    CNode *m_History;

public:
    CFile(void) : m_LenHistory(1), m_History(new CNode) {}

    friend void swap(CFile& a, CFile& b) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a.m_LenHistory, b.m_LenHistory);
        swap(a.m_History, b.m_History);
    }

    CFile(const CFile &src) : m_LenHistory(src.m_LenHistory) {
        CNode** dcur = &m_History;
        for (CNode* scur = src.m_History; scur; scur = scur->next) {
            *dcur = new CNode;
            (*dcur)->data = scur->data;
            dcur = &(*dcur)->next;
        }
    }

    CFile& operator=(CFile src) {
        swap(*this, src);
        return *this;
    }

    ~CFile(void) {
        delete m_History;
    }

    uint32_t write(const uint8_t *src, uint32_t bytes) {
        return m_History->data.write(src, bytes);
    }
    uint32_t read(uint8_t* dst, uint32_t bytes) {
        return m_History->data.read(dst, bytes);
    }
    bool seek(uint32_t offset) {
        return m_History->data.seek(offset);
    }
    void truncate(void) {
        m_History->data.truncate();
    }
    uint32_t fileSize(void) const { return m_History->data.length(); }

    void addVersion(void) {   
        CNode* head = new CNode;
        head->data = m_History->data;
        head->next = m_History;
        m_History = head;
        ++m_LenHistory;
    }

    bool undoVersion(void) {
        if (m_LenHistory == 1)
            return false;
        CNode* head = m_History;
        m_History = head->next;
        head->next = nullptr;
        delete head;
        --m_LenHistory;
        return true;
    }

    uint32_t lenHistory() const {
        return m_LenHistory;
    }
};



bool writeTest(CFile& x, const std::initializer_list<uint8_t>& data, uint32_t wrLen)
{
    return x.write(data.begin(), data.size()) == wrLen;
}

bool readTest(CFile& x, const std::initializer_list<uint8_t>& data)
{
    auto* tmp = new uint8_t[data.size()];
    uint32_t idx = 0;
    bool ret = true;

    if (x.read(tmp, data.size()) != data.size())
        ret = false;
    else {
        for (auto v : data) {
            if (tmp[idx++] != v) {
                ret = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] tmp;
    return ret;
}



int main(void)
{
    {
        CFile f0;
        assert(writeTest(f0, { 10, 20, 30 }, 3));
        assert(f0.fileSize() == 3);
        assert(writeTest(f0, { 60, 70, 80 }, 3));
        assert(f0.fileSize() == 6);
        assert(f0.seek(2));
        assert(writeTest(f0, { 5, 4 }, 2));
        assert(f0.fileSize() == 6);
        assert(f0.seek(1));
        assert(readTest(f0, { 20, 5, 4, 70, 80 }));
        assert(f0.seek(3));
        f0.addVersion();
        assert(f0.seek(6));
        assert(writeTest(f0, { 100, 101, 102, 103 }, 4));
        f0.addVersion();
        assert(f0.seek(5));
        CFile f1(f0);
        f0.truncate();
        assert(f0.seek(0));
        assert(readTest(f0, { 10, 20, 5, 4, 70 }));
        assert(f0.undoVersion());
        assert(f0.seek(0));
        assert(readTest(f0, { 10, 20, 5, 4, 70, 80, 100, 101, 102, 103 }));
        assert(f0.undoVersion());
        assert(f0.seek(0));
        assert(readTest(f0, { 10, 20, 5, 4, 70, 80 }));
        assert(!f0.seek(100));
        assert(writeTest(f1, { 200, 210, 220 }, 3));
        assert(f1.seek(0));
        assert(readTest(f1, { 10, 20, 5, 4, 70, 200, 210, 220, 102, 103 }));
        std::cout << f1.lenHistory() << std::endl;
        //std::cout << f1.m_History->m_Data << std::endl;
        assert(f1.undoVersion());
        std::cout << f1.lenHistory() << std::endl;
        assert(f1.undoVersion());
        assert(readTest(f1, { 4, 70, 80 }));
        assert(!f1.undoVersion());
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // remove this if you are not using Visual Studio
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While I agree with "learning is good" in general, I would rather people *learn* std:: first, boost:: second, and several other third-party libs third *before* setting out to implement data structures. The cases where you really *have* to roll your own are few, very far between, and certainly not for a beginner to solve...

Comment: @DevSolar if you never try to implement your own double linked list or red black tree, I doubt that you'll be ever think of rolling your own *new* data structure.

Comment: @DevSolar But you're right. You definitely should learn std::, boost:: and other libraries. I'd just suggest moving in parallel more than in sequence.

Comment: The point being, the need of "rolling your own new data structure" should hardly ever arise. And if it does, only far, *far* down the road. Whereas practicing to "roll your own" early on tempts you to "oh, I know this" and rolling your own instead of "oh, I know this" and using what is there. Virtually none of the homegrown containers I have seen play ball with `<algorithms>` or iterators, for example...